# Do i need drivers separately to install Ubuntu 64-bit in my vostro 2520

Tags: system-installation

My laptop is Dell Vostro 2520. It came with Ubuntu as inbuilt OS. But I installed windows 7. Now I want to install Ubuntu in it. Does it requires any drivers? I have this doubt because dell is not providing any drivers for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it requires any drivers. why because dell is not providing any drivers for Ubuntu

Yes but we do not require you to search for drivers for your system.

ALL Linux systems provide generic drivers for hardware that create a working Ubuntu system. Besides that you also get 3rd party drivers for your video card if it is nVidia or AMD. And sometimes you need a 3rd party driver for your network card.